# Find number of integers (excluding special characters) before decimal using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a number 12,234,123.23 in which I use a split method as follows :

```
num1= number.toString().split(".")[0];
// num1.length returns 10.
```

But I want only the number of integers (that is => 8 (excluding commas) to be returned.

Kindly suggest a way in which I could achieve it using JavaScript

Comment: You could have an if statement in a loop, and check for modulus 1 to see if it's a whole number

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "12,234,123.23";
str = str.replace(/,/g, "");

var index = str.indexOf(".");

str = str.substr(0, index); // 12234123

console.log(str);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sm3fM/

Answer (score 0):

The above code will work in this case. But as you mentioned in the title, if you want to exclude any special characters then use of regular expressions will be the more precise & cleaner way.You have to create a regEx pattern and then validate your input to that pattern. more on regExp with examples can be found at:

1. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in one line:

```
parseInt(str.replace(/,/g, ""))
```

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nn007/sm3fM/1/